# How do I open Anaconda prompt using the python library os?

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to open Anaconda prompt using the python subprocess library, I also need to be able to enter commands in it.

I ams using anaconda

spyder 4

python 3.7

windows 10

Comment: Why do you insist on using `os`, and not any other tool for the purpose? (In general, the preferred module for running external programs is `subprocess`).

Comment: huh i never thought of that

Comment: How would i use subprocess

Comment: Depends on the details. Are you already running in a terminal window, or do you need to start one? Just which kind of "Anaconda prompt" are you talking about -- a Python REPL, or something else? (What would you do or type to open the kind of prompt you want if *not* from existing Python code?)

Comment: I don't understand can you elaborate or give an example